# Using normals in DirectX 10

Tags: c++, shaders, directx, normals

I've got a working OBJ loader that loads vertices, indices, texture coordinates, and normals. As of right now it doesn't process texture coordinates or normals but it stores them in arrays and creates a valid mesh with the vertices and indices.

Now I am trying to figure out how can I make the shader use the correct normal in the array for the current vertex if I can't `setnormals()` to my mesh. If I were to just use an index in my array of normals corresponding to the index in the vertices, how would I retrieve the current index the shader is processing? BTW: I am trying to write a blinn-phong shader technique.

Also when I create the input layout and I've added the semantic `NORMAL` to it, how would I list the multiple semantics in that single parameter? Would I just separate it with a space?

PS: If you need to see any code, just let me know.

Comment: Short question, why not use DirectX 9 or 11?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is slightly ambigious, but if you're actually asking if you can use the triples to sample buffers arbitrarily from your shader, you can (in D3D11) use some `StructuredBuffer<T>` in your shader and index those with each of your index values. If you're stuck on D3D10, you could make a horrible approximation with Vertex-Texture-Fetch from a FP texture holding your geometry values. If this is not what you wanted to know, read below on how to make an multi-indexed mesh single-indexed.

When D3D (and OpenGL) does indexed rendering they sample the streams of attributes at the same index in all vertex attribute streams. This means that if you've got index `i`, you get a vertex made up of `position[i]`, `texcoord[i]`, and `normal[i]`.

OBJ on the other side has faces made up of separate indices for each attribute, where a triple `p/t/n` is intended to gather `position[p]`, `texcoord[t]`, `normal[n]`.

The traditional way to solve this is to while processing your OBJ file, you build a new set of single-indexed vertices. This can be as easy as gathering the attributes corresponding to the `p/t/n` triples, putting the corresponding attributes into a sequence and using the sequence position as the single-index to use.

An optimization is to keep track of which elements of the new buffer corresponds to the attributes for a `p/t/n` triple and reuse those elements if the same triple occurs multiple times, with a `map<Triple,Index>` or so.